# Multiplication between different rows of a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, row

I have several dataframes looking like this:

| time_hr | cell_hour | id | attitude | hour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.028611 | xxx | 1 | Cruise | 1.0 |
| 0.028333 | xxx | 4 | Cruise | 1.0 |
| 0.004722 | xxx | 16 | Cruise | 1.0 |

I want to do a specific multiplications between rows of the 'time_hr' column.
I need to multiply each row with other rows and store the value to use later.
eg. if the column values are [2,3,4], I would need 2x3, 2x4, 3x2, 3x4, 4x2, 4x3 values.
A part of the problem is that I have several dataframes which have different number of rows so I would need a generic way of doing this.
Is there a way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a cartesian product to me:

```py
from io import StringIO
#sample data reading
data1 = """
time_hr cell_hour   id  attitude    hour
0.028611    xxx 1   Cruise  1.0
0.028333    xxx 4   Cruise  1.0
0.004722    xxx 16  Cruise  1.0
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data1), sep="\t")

#filtering dataset to needed columns
df_time = df[["id", "time_hr"]]
df_comb = df_time.merge(df_time, how='cross')
df_comb = df_comb[df_comb["id_x"] != df_comb["id_y"]]
df_comb["time_hr"] = df_comb["time_hr_x"] * df_comb["time_hr_y"]
df_comb.drop(columns=["time_hr_x", "time_hr_y"]).set_index(["id_x", "id_y"])

#               time_hr
#id_x   id_y    
#1      4       0.000811
#       16      0.000135
#4      1       0.000811
#       16      0.000134
#16     1       0.000135
#       4       0.000134
```

If you want to have more pythonic code you automatise it

```
id_column = "id"
product_columns = ["time_hr"]

df_time = df[[id_column, *product_columns]]
df_comb = df_time.merge(df_time, how='cross')
df_comb = df_comb[df_comb[f"{id_column}_x"] != df_comb[f"{id_column}_y"]]
for column in product_columns:
    df_comb[column] = df_comb[f"{column}_x"] * df_comb[f"{column}_y"]
df_comb.set_index([f"{id_column}_x", f"{id_column}_y"])\
    .drop(columns=[drop for column in product_columns for drop in [f"{column}_x", f"{column}_y"]])
```

PS. I am not sure if that is what you were trying to achieve, if not, please add expected output data for those 3 input rows.

Comment: When I try this I'm getting a key error 'KeyError: 'cross''. I tried to write it as if merging two different dataframes but it still gives the same error.

Comment: If you got  `'KeyError: 'cross''` that means, that you have pandas <= 1.1 `cross` comes in with pandas 1.2: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2/reference/api/pandas.merge.html